# Make Scala's implicitNotFound annotation more precise

Tags: scala, typeclass

I'm having some problems with typeclasses in Scala and more precisely with errors at compile time when a typeclass instance cannot be found. Let's say that I have a typeclass `TC` and an object `B[C]` that has an instance of `TC` only if `C` has an instance of `TC`. In Scala this can be written `implicit def btc[C](implicit ctc: TC[C]) = new TC[B[C]] { ... }`. When you need a `TC[B[C]]` for a `C` for which scalac cannot find an instance `TC[C]`, scalac will give an error saying that it cannot find a `TC[B[C]]`. While this is true, the error message is missing the reason why scalac cannot find `TC[B[C]]`, that is that it cannot find `TC[C]`.

To illustrate the problem, I decided to make a small toy example where `TC` is `PrettyPrintable`, `C` is `Unit` and `B` is `Option`:

```scala
import scala.annotation.implicitNotFound

@implicitNotFound("Cannot pretty print instances of the type ${T}")
trait PrettyPrintable[T] {
  def prettyPrint(t: T): String
}

object PrettyPrintable {
  def apply[T](implicit pp: PrettyPrintable[T]): PrettyPrintable[T] = pp

  implicit def optPP[T](implicit opp: PrettyPrintable[T]) = new PrettyPrintable[Option[T]] {
    override def prettyPrint(ot: Option[T]): String = ot.fold("")(opp.prettyPrint)
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  println(PrettyPrintable[Option[Unit]].prettyPrint(None)) // error
}
```

If I run the application, I get the error:

```scala
[error] /home/rief/prog/scala/implicitNotFoundTest/Main.scala:24: Cannot pretty print instances of the type Option[Unit]
[error]   println(PrettyPrintable[Option[Unit]].prettyPrint(None))
```

This is of course true: scalac can't find a pretty print instance for type `Option[Unit]`. The problem is that the error itself is not very helpful because the point is not that scalac can't find an instance of the type class but more why it cannot find it. In this case, the reason why `Option[Unit]` doesn't have a pretty print instance is because `Unit` doesn't have a pretty print instance but for more complex cases this can be a nightmare.

My question is: is it possible to make errors on implicit not found more precise?

Comment: That's a good one. I had considered once about what context to expose to an interpolator for the annotation string, but I hadn't thought about implicit search history. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7411

Answer (score 1):

That would be nice, but I think the problem you want to solve is a bit more complicated than it seems at first blush. In this example, I've added some more implicit vals and defs for `PrettyPrintable`:

```
import scala.annotation.implicitNotFound

@implicitNotFound("Cannot pretty print instances of the type ${T}")
trait PrettyPrintable[T] {
  def prettyPrint(t: T): String
}

object PrettyPrintable {
  def apply[T](implicit pp: PrettyPrintable[T]): PrettyPrintable[T] = pp

  implicit val intPP = new PrettyPrintable[Int] {
    override def prettyPrint(i: Int): String = s"== $i =="
  }

  implicit def optPP[T](implicit opp: PrettyPrintable[T]) = new PrettyPrintable[Option[T]] {
    override def prettyPrint(ot: Option[T]): String = s"-- ${ot.map(opp.prettyPrint)} --"
  }

  implicit def pairPP[T, U](implicit tpp: PrettyPrintable[T], upp: PrettyPrintable[U]) =
    new PrettyPrintable[(T, U)] {
      override def prettyPrint(pair: (T, U)): String =
        s"[[[ ${tpp.prettyPrint(pair._1)} >>> ${upp.prettyPrint(pair._2)} ]]]"
    }

}

object Main extends App {
  println(PrettyPrintable[Int].prettyPrint(6))                   // prints == 6 ==
  println(PrettyPrintable[Option[Int]].prettyPrint(None))        // prints -- None --
  println(PrettyPrintable[Option[Int]].prettyPrint(Some(6)))     // prints -- Some(== 6 ==) --
  println(PrettyPrintable[(Int,Int)].prettyPrint((6 -> 7)))      // prints [[[ == 6 == >>> == 7 == ]]]
  println(PrettyPrintable[(Float,Long)].prettyPrint((6F -> 7L))) // error
}
```

The last line produces the following compiler error, analogous to the error from your example:

```
Cannot pretty print instances of the type (Float, Long)
```

In your case, it is easy to cast the blame for not finding an implicit `PrettyPrintable[Option[Unit]]` on not finding an implicit `PrettyPrintable[Unit]`. But in the case of the pair, would you want to blame not finding an implicit `PrettyPrintable[(Float, Long)]` on not finding an implicit `PrettyPrintable[Float]`, not finding an implicit `PrettyPrintable[Long]`, or both?

Note that the root cause of the implicit resolution failure might not even have the same shape as the original. For instance, consider adding the following two implicit defs:

```
implicit def i2ppf(implicit i: Int) = new PrettyPrintable[Float] {
  override def prettyPrint(f: Float): String = s"xx $f xx"
}

implicit def s2ppf(implicit s: String) = new PrettyPrintable[Float] {
  override def prettyPrint(f: Float): String = s"xx $f xx"
}
```

Now, is the root cause not finding an implicit `Int`, or not finding an implicit `String`? The actual answer is very complicated. Something like this:

- there was no implicit `PrettyPrintable[(Float,Long)]` because:

  - there was no implicit value with that precise type, AND
  - there were not implicits for both `PrettyPrintable[Float]` and `PrettyPrintable[Long]`

    - there was no implicit for `PrettyPrintable[Float]` because:

      - there was no implicit value with that precise type, AND
      - there was no implicit `Int`, AND
      - there was no implicit `String`
    - there was no implicit for `PrettyPrintable[Long]` because:

      - there was no implicit value with that precise type

In answer to your question, "is it possible to make errors on implicit not found more precise?", I think that would involve providing you some kind of programmatic access to a wide tree of possibilities for you to construct an error message more precisely in the general case. Just designing a decent API for the job would be a pretty impressive undertaking, let alone an implementation of that API.

Comment: The compiler can also prune trees like the one above for performance reasons. For instance, the compiler probably didn't even consider implicits for `PrettyPrintable[Long]` once it failed to find an implicit for `PrettyPrintable[Float]`

Comment: I don't think the question is quite this complicated. In the case of `PP[(Float, Long)]`, ideally the error message would indicate which of the two instances are missing, or both, if that's the case. And your latter examples are implicit conversions that take a form you don't normally see when working with type classes.

Comment: @TravisBrown do you want to propose a solution that will handle the general case? Even in the simple case you propose, that the error message should "indicate which of the two instances are missing, or both, if that's the case", how are you going to construct such an error message? How far are you going to take it? Are you going to handle `PP[(((A,B),(C,D),E),(F,G))]`?

Comment: Keep in mind that the error message is constructed by the user, using a little DSL provided internally by the compiler, as specified in this API: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.implicitNotFound what is this DSL going to look like to handle even the simple cases?

Comment: There's a parallel conversation [on Twitter right now](https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/649594203664740352)—I think you could accomplish what the OP wants with a macro, but I'm not sure it's worth it.